# Remote control session lock state

Tags: c++, winapi

Для того чтобы понять что сессия заблокирована (CTRL+ALT+DEL -> Lock) используется следующий кусок кода:

```
if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, sessionId, WTSSessionInfoEx, &buffer, &size) == TRUE && size > 0)
{
   const WTSINFOEXW *info = reinterpret_cast<WTSINFOEXW *>(buffer);
   if (info->Level == 1)
   {
      LONG flags = info->Data.WTSInfoExLevel1.SessionFlags;
      return flags & WTS_SESSIONSTATE_LOCK;
   }
}
```

Но этот код не работает в случае если мы подключились удаленно через Win Remote Control. `flags` имеет `WTS_SESSION_REMOTE_CONTROL`но при этом отсутствует флаг `WTS_SESSIONSTATE_LOCK`. Значит ли это, что при Win Remote Control не возможно узнать заблокирована ли сессия или нет? Если можно, тогда подскажите каким способом?

Comment: А она разве при удаленном подключении не разблокируется?

Comment: Возможно, но тут случай когда вы удаленно подключены и блокируете удаленную машину. Например CTRL+ALT+END.

Comment: что используетсся в качестве значений sessionId ?